# Change Xsensors in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Bionic to display Fahrenheit?

Tags: 18.04, temperature, lm-sensors

I have installed Xsensors and the graphic user interface is awesome.  I can manually go into the the terminal and type

```
sensors -f
```

and retrieve the temp in Fahrenheit. (from what I read this is an lm-sensors program answer).

But how can I modify **X sensors** to automatically put out this information from Celsius to Fahrenheit on the graphic user interface?

I need details as I'm a noob in this situation, but I'm pretty resourceful in doing things.  Not a coder or anything like that.

[image: Xsensors currently shows this on the Graphic User Interface]

Answer (score 0):

The same way as with `sensors`:

```
xsensors -f
```

Use man:

```
man xsensors
```

It displays:

```
OPTIONS
       -f     display all temperatures in Fahrenheit.
```

Comment: THANKS! but this option only allows it to display this while terminal is open.  was hoping for a more permanent solution.  click the icon added to the favorites, the program opens and automatically displays the temp in Fahrenheit.    thanks in advance!